# setZoom method not refreshing map view in android

Tags: android, google-maps, refresh, android-mapview

I searched long time for any answer of this question, but I could not find any.

My question is: I have a map view and its controller. I adjust zoom to 15 at first by the setZoom method, add overlays and animate to some points. They are all working very well. But then when I called setZoom method again, the map view is not refreshing itself. I tried 'invalidate' and 'postInvalidate' methods, but did not work. I just paid attention that after last setZoom method is called when I try to zoom by my hand, the map view is refreshed suddenly. But this is not a solution of course.

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
      mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say, I am talking about maps api v1 not v2. So 'moveCamera' method does not exist in my case.